# Padding doesn't work when aligned to bottom in Relative Layout

Tags: android

This is my problem:

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_image"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32p"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

My ImageView inside RelativeLayout is not displayed with any padding. It is displayed like padding is 0dp. I need to have that image in bottom right corner and it needs to have some padding. What can I do to accomplish that?

Comment: try setting the `android:src= @drawable\my_pic.png` and change `android:layout_height="32dp"` not 32p and check

Comment: Maybe related to layout_height="wrap_content"? Since I don't know the context of this file, maybe using it with a match_parent helps

Comment: try to add android:scaleType="centerInside"

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure that you do not confuse padding with margin.

2) Change 32p to 32dp

3) If you are setting width/height to 32dp, and padding to 10dp, your image can have only 12do width and height, because of padding you set with fixed image dimensions.

4) Remember that if you set padding too big, your image may even dont show.